# Windows DNS and long DKIM keys

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, dkim, dmarc, windows-dns

One of our third party services that we sends as provided us with a DKIM record that is longer than 255 characters and they won't provide a shorter one. How do I properly use what they've provided with Windows DNS?

I've tried the following solutions but mxtoolbox fails to find the dkim record or doesn't recognize it.

I'm looking for help specifically with this issue related to Windows DNS server.

http://hack.limbicmedia.ca/how-to-split-dns-dkim-records-properly/

[https://xeams.com/ms-dns.htm#:~:text=Step-by-step%20Instructions.%201%20Open%20DNS%20Manager%20by%20typing,display%20the%20full%20record%20as%20shown%20below.%20](https://xeams.com/ms-dns.htm#:%7E:text=Step-by-step%20Instructions.%201%20Open%20DNS%20Manager%20by%20typing,display%20the%20full%20record%20as%20shown%20below.%20)

[How do I enter a strong (long) DKIM key into DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/255580/how-do-i-enter-a-strong-long-dkim-key-into-dns)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering I was using a multi line format in the TXT record with quotes at the beginning and end of each line. After remove quotes DKIM check worked.